# How could I write a base case for this algorithm?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

I'm having trouble with the algorithm: what I need to do is multiply the elements of the array via recursion. Here's what I've got so far:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    void vector(int vec[],int tam) {
    // gets a simple array
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<tam; i++) {
            printf("Ingrese un numero: ");
            scanf("%d",&vec[i]);
        }
    }
    int mv(int vec[], int tam, int pos) {
     // need help with the base and general case!
        if (tam==0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return vec[pos]*mv(vec,tam,pos+1);
        }   
    }

    int main() {
        int vec[3];
        vector(vec,3);
        printf("%d",mv(vec,3,0));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base case is `if (pos == tam) return 1;`

You also have to make sure array is not empty